# PHPUnit fails on HHVM because of Fatal error: Class undefined: PHP_Token_HASHBANG

Tags: php, phpunit, travis-ci, hhvm

On my Travis CI builds ive phpunit failures when testing in HHVM. This is the full exception:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Fatal error: Class undefined: PHP_Token_HASHBANG in phar://phpunit-4.5.0.phar/php-token-stream/Token/Stream.php on line 185
```

Running `PHPUnit 4.8.14` with the following commandline:

```
phpunit --verbose --coverage-clover build/logs/clover.xml
```

How to fix this?

Comment: how up to date is hhvm? I found [this](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4936) github issue which references that same error message that seems to have since been fixed

Comment: On Travis, it reports HipHop VM 3.6.6 (rel). Just found out that another project of mine builds fine on the same HHVM version, this is really confusing me.

Comment: Travis CI precise containers are stuck on HHVM 3.6.6 since that is the last HHVM version for ubuntu precise. To get the newer releases you have to use the slower non-container Trusty build (at least until they release the Trusty container).
With Trusty builds you can get latest hhvm (currently 3.15.2) hhvm-nightly (currently 3.16.0-dev) or LTS versions (3.15, 3.12, etc)

See this for how to do HHVM on Travis since May 2016 https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php#HHVM-versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't very clear to me, anyway it was related to the PHPUnit version in HHVM. In order to fix this i've added phpunit as a dependency to my project

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.*"
},
```

so that it is updated to the latest 4.x version, than updated my travis script

```
script:
  - vendor/bin/phpunit
```

This fixed.